# Why does not the margin:auto tag work on the "title" div?

Tags: html, css

Here are the following html and CSS code for my webpage. I cannot seem to center the title div which is inside the header div. I am confused whether this problem is due to positioning or display. Thanks.

```css
#header {
  position: absolute;
  position: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #3e8dff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#image {
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
#image a img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
}
#navBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #96CDCD;
  top: 120px;
  left: -15px;
}
#navBar ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#top_left {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 48%;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #00FA9A;
}
#top_right {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #40E0D0;
  opacity: .7;
}
#bot_left {
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
  height: 500px;
  width: 48%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 700px;
  left: 0px;
}
#bot_right {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: purple;
  top: 700px;
  right: 0px;
}
.simplePar {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
#title {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 90px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page 1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">

    <div id="image">
      <a href="http://google.com/">
        <img src="C:\Users\Raiyan\Desktop\files for website\google-logo.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="title">
      pasa
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navBar">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Latest News</li>
      <li>Buy Tickets</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>More Info</li>
      <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div id="top_left">
    <p class="simplePar">All of these are under the <span>divs</span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div id="top_right">
    <p class="simplePar">All of these are under the <span>divs</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="bot_left">
    <p class="simplePar">All of these are under the <span>divs</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="bot_right">
    <p class="simplePar">All of these are under the <span>divs</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are mixing several positioning systems in your code (floats, absolutes, inlines...). Can I simplify your markup?

Comment: yes please. I am still learning and very much confused about where and when to use positioning, display and floats. Please suggest me something so that i can clearly understand it. @Vi100

Comment: You have too much html elements for your header, so you end up with too many and mor complex css rules for your layout. By general rule try to use the fewer elements you need to accomplish what you want and try to be as "semantic" as possible. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many divs and styles for such a simple structure. Of course this can be done in a plenty of ways, here you have one of them:

```
<div id="header">
  <a href="http://google.com/"><img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Example_logo.jpg"></a>
  <span>pasa</span>
</div>

#header { 
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 120px;
    font-size:24px;
}

#image
{
    height: 120px;
    width: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

If what you want is the title centered on the remaining space after the image (instead of centered in the page itself) then just remove the position:absolute style and put the float:left instead.

You should simplify the markup and then your style rules will be easier to understand (for you and for the browser...). You also have errors like:

```
 position: block;
```

wich doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Set #title to inline and then give it a text-align of center:

```css
#header {
  position: absolute;
  position: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #3e8dff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#image {
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
#image a img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
}
#navBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #96CDCD;
  top: 120px;
  left: -15px;
}
#navBar ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#top_left {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 48%;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #00FA9A;
}
#top_right {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #40E0D0;
  opacity: .7;
}
#bot_left {
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
  height: 500px;
  width: 48%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 700px;
  left: 0px;
}
#bot_right {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: purple;
  top: 700px;
  right: 0px;
}
.simplePar {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
#title {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  text-align:center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 90px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page 1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">

    <div id="image">
      <a href="http://google.com/">
        <img src="C:\Users\Raiyan\Desktop\files for website\google-logo.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="title">
      pasa
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navBar">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Latest News</li>
      <li>Buy Tickets</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>More Info</li>
      <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div id="top_left">
    <p class="simplePar">All of these are under the <span>divs</span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div id="top_right">
    <p class="simplePar">All of these are under the <span>divs</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="bot_left">
    <p class="simplePar">All of these are under the <span>divs</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="bot_right">
    <p class="simplePar">All of these are under the <span>divs</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `div#title`'s position is set to absolute. `margin: 0 auto` does not work with absolute positioned elements, because they are taken out of context.

Answer (score -1):

change for #title {display: block; position: relative;}
You are displaing by innerhitteng block of upper, ans position absolute will not work as said @Paul in message before !!!